# How to verify that input is numeric in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is the code that I have written to get the corresponsing alphabetic grade for each numerical grade. I want to make sure that the user doesn't enter any strings or characters as input. Only numbers. So I used isnumeric function but the code doesn't work and the while loop doesn't break when I enter a string. It just give me an error. Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
c=input('What is your grade?  ');
   while 1
if  ~isnumeric(c)
    break
end
if c>=90 && c<=100
   disp('A');
elseif c<90 && c>=80
    disp('B');
else
    disp('F');
end
   end
```

Comment: Isn't the `while 1` the wrong place?

Comment: @Paolo   Even when I move it to the top  I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`validateattributes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html). It is much more powerful than a simple `isnumeric`, e.g. you can specify a range in which the number should lie: `{'>',0,'<',10}` or ask themt o be `nonnegative`

```
validateattributes(x,{'numeric'},{'nonnegative'})
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` evaluates what the user enters*. If what the user enters is not a valid MATLAB expression, then you see an error message. Instead,

```
c = input('What is your grade?  ', 's');
```

The `'s'` argument makes it so that the function returns exactly what the user typed, as a string. You can then use `str2double` to convert that to a number. If it's not a number, NaN will be returned. You can test for this:

```matlab
while true
   c = input('What is your grade?  ', 's');
   c = str2double(c);
   if isnan(c)
      break
   end
   disp(c)
end
```

---

* This evaluation actually makes `input` dangerous to use in this form, for example the user can enter `delete('c:/windows')` or something like that to destroy your system.